# passing argument values into by condition for anti join in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to pass the argument values from command line script to the join condition in anti join in the by section. The default format is anti_join(df1,df2,by=c("a" ="b"). I am trying to substitute the values of  a and b with the argument values received from command line script

```
require("dplyr")
# storing the joining keys in separate variables 
a.id <- c("EMP_CLIENT_ID")  
b.id <- c("VEND_CLIENT_ID") 
#No issues while running the below line 
diff1 <- anti_join(Src_df,Tgt_df,by=c("EMP_CLIENT_ID"="VEND_CLIENT_ID"))
```

Getting error when I tried to use like below

```
diff1 <- anti_join(Src_df,Tgt_df,by=c(a.id = b.id))
```

How to pass arguments values in the join condition of anti_join ?

Comment: If it is an object use `setNames` i.e. `by = setNames(b.id, a.id))`

Comment: Thanks Akrun. It worked :) Just for understanding , why setNames(b.id, a.id) is given in reverse order?

Comment: If you check the output `c(a = 5)` and `nm <- a; setNames(5, nm)` it becomes clear